# How do I move a painted line in Java,using my mouse?

Tags: java

I hava a project which will look like similar to Paint program. Here, I'm supposed to draw lines with start and end points and then I need to be able to move these lines by simply dragging my mouse on them.
I draw the lines using the drawLine method of Java. The problem is, I have no idea how to move these lines :(

Please help me if you have an idea on this,
Thanks.

Comment: -1: Too abstract. It can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9UdixYZ9F0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some sort of ActionListener and detect when the user clicks a line on the screen. Then you need to monitor the mouse movement; and rePaint() the line.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should clear the canvas on the mouseMove event  with fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)   on the graphics objet  , and within the event get the mouse location.

```
 public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) {  // called during motion when no buttons are down
      mx = e.getX();
      my = e.getY();

      repaint();
   }
```

then in your paint method  you should draw the line using mx, my coordinates aproprietly